# fff: mocking a value returned by reference from another module

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, fake-function-framework

Working with the [Fake Function Framework](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff), I have this bit of code (paraphrased):

```
void sched_step(void) {
    event_t event;
    int status;

    status = queue_fetch(&event);
    if (status == OK) {
        do_something_with(&event);
        ...
    }
}
```

When writing unit tests for the `sched` module, I want to control what queue_fetch() returns by reference, that is, I want to fake the value of `event` *without dragging in the entire `queue` module*.

I haven't been able to wrap my head around how to do this in fff.  Can someone show me the way?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find some inspiration in the examples for mocking an external dependency: https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff/blob/master/examples/embedded_ui/src/UI_test_ansic.c

And the readme contains some help on [how to return a reference from a fake](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L456).